# Query to get first 3 images in Wikidata page

Tags: sparql, wdqs

I'm trying to query data from species' pages on Wikidata with the following query :

```
SELECT ?animal ?animalLabel ?iucncode ?photo WHERE {
    VALUES ?iucncode { "714" }
?animal wdt:P627 ?iucncode
OPTIONAL {
    ?animal wdt:P18 ?photo.
}
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
```

[See it working here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fanimal%20%3FanimalLabel%20%3Fiucncode%20%3Fphoto%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%3Fiucncode%20%7B%20%22714%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fanimal%20wdt%3AP627%20%3Fiucncode%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fanimal%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fphoto.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)

I'm changing the value of `?iucncode` to get data about different species. With the current query I get as many results as there are images, for a single page. I would like to have a response with a single line for each page, with 3 columns of data for the first 3 images (if available). Is there a way to do that with SPARQL ?

For the species in the example above, instead of having 4 lines with these columns :

| animal | animalLabel | iucncode | photo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

I would like to have a single line like so :

| animal | animalLabel | iucncode | photo_1 | photo_2 | photo_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
SELECT 
?animal ?animalLabel ?iucncode 
(SAMPLE(?photo1) as ?photo1) 
(SAMPLE(?photo2) as ?photo2) 
(SAMPLE(?photo3) as ?photo3) 

WHERE {
    
  VALUES ?iucncode { "714"  "6736" "550" "899" }
    
  ?animal wdt:P627 ?iucncode
            
    OPTIONAL {
        ?animal wdt:P18 ?photo1.
    }
    
  BIND(IF( BOUND( ?photo1), ?photo1,"NA1") AS ?photo1)
  
      OPTIONAL {
        ?animal wdt:P18 ?photo2.
        FILTER ( ?photo1 != ?photo2)
    }
    
  BIND(IF( BOUND( ?photo2), ?photo2,"NA2") AS ?photo2)

    OPTIONAL {
        ?animal wdt:P18 ?photo3.
        FILTER ( ?photo1 != ?photo3)
        FILTER ( ?photo2 != ?photo3)
    }
      
  BIND(IF( BOUND( ?photo3), ?photo3,"NA3") AS ?photo3)

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
    }

GROUP BY ?animal ?animalLabel ?iucncode
```

[image: Result on WDQS]
You can also see it on the WDQS: https://w.wiki/3WUi

### Quick explanation:

- Pattern `OPTIONAL + FILTER (?A != ?B)` for getting distinct photo on each variable
- Pattern `BIND(IF( BOUND( ?a), ?a,"NA") AS ?a)` for making sure there is some result returned for each variable, even if there was no match on Wikidata
- Pattern `?a (SAMPLE (?b) as ?b) (SAMPLE (?c) as ?c) + GROUP BY ?a` to get single results and eliminate duplicates

There might be smarter ways to solve it, though.

Comment: That works well, thanks ! Thanks also for the explanation.